# Set value for a dynamic key in pydantic

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

I have a pydantic model like below

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
        
class Quote(BaseModel):
    id: str
    uuid: str
    name: Optional[str]
    customer: Optional[str]
    vendor: Optional[str]
```

In my code we will have either customer or vendor key.

```
quote = Quote()
quote.id = "adf908"
quote.uuid = "04f28afd-eede-448a-9cdc-9349b78f88f9"

vendor_customer = return "vendor" if quote.name == "pet" else "customer"
```

Now I need to set a value to the vendor/customer field in my pydantic model.

Comment: Your code examples have syntax errors. I also do not understand how are you instantiating a `Quote` without passing values for the required fields `id` and `uuid`. Should the value of `customer` and `vendor` depend on the value of `name`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `setattr`. Like this:

```
quote = Quote(**{"id": "adf908", "uuid": "04f28afd-eede-448a-9cdc-9349b78f88f9"})
vendor_customer = "vendor" if quote.name == "pet" else "customer"
setattr(quote, vendor_customer, "test")
```